# Como pegar o ID da DropDownList e passar para uma variavel em jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o seguinte DropDownList:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", String.Empty)
        </div>
```

E essa função jQuery que quando o usuário apertar o botão vai pegar o valor selecionado e jogar em uma table:

```
function AddRow()
    {
       var produto = $("ProdutoId")
       $('#tabelaPedidos').append('<tr><td>' + produto  + '</td><td>teste</td></tr>')
    }
```

Porém não consigo pegar o ID do DropDownList para pegar o valor selecionado...

Assim que preencho meu DropDownList

```
ViewBag.ProdutoId = new SelectList(context.Produtos, "ID", "Nome", pedido.ProdutoId);
```

Comment: qual html é gerado com o comando "@Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", String.Empty)"?

Comment: Um dropdownlist com meus produtos carregados...

Answer (score 2):

> Dessa forma você não está selecionando o `id` do DropDown, e nem pegando o valor selecionado.

Vamos por partes.
Primeiro, para selecionar um elemento pelo id você usa essa "sintaxe":

```
var elemento = $('#IDAqui');
```

O sinal de "jogo da velha" **#** indica isso. Então para selecionar o DropDown você deveria usar isso:

```
var produto = $("#ProdutoId");
```

Porém, você ainda não selecionou o valor, muito menos o item selecionado. Para isso, você precisa filtrar o selecionado e após obter seu valor. Ficaria assim seu código completo:

```
function AddRow()
    {
       var produto = $('#ProdutoId option:selected').val();
       $('#tabelaPedidos').append('<tr><td>' + produto  + '</td><td>teste</td></tr>')
    }
```

Dessa forma você está selecionando o elemento pelo id e após obtendo a opção que está selecionada (`option:selected`) e então obtendo seu valor (`.val()`).

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu quero fazer...só que desse jeito que vc disse eu to pegando um numero por exemplo 5...o "selectedIndex" inves do "selectedValue" será que eu to preenchendo esse dropDownList de jeito errado ? vou editar no codigo como estou fazendo